# c++ how to convert function arguments to strings

Tags: c++, string

I have a function below `input` which takes 4 arguments. Inside the function I would like to recreate the function call as a string and write it to a file.

For example this function could be called with:

```
input = cm.input(mv::Shape(224, 224, 3), mv::DType::Float, mv::Order::Planar);
```

What would be the best way to convert the arguments to strings? After that I plan to concat them.

I appreciate any advice on where to start.

```
mv::Model::input(const Shape& shape, DType dType, Order order, const string& name)
{
//Create string of function call
}
```

Comment: There is `std::to_string` function. If that is what you are after. If you are looking for some kind of language reflection then you are out of luck.

Comment: what you want to do is only possible with some major restrictions. Consider `void foo(int)` where you cannot (inside the function) distinguish between a call `foo(3)` and `foo(1+2)` and `foo(x)` (where `x==3`). This might be fine for you, but i doubt that you can unambigously detect inside the function that the `Shape` object was created by that constructor call `v::Shape(224, 224, 3)`

Comment: ...or you enter the evil side and use macros, then (almost) anything is possible ;)

Comment: Best to just write your own custom code. Custom for each function call you want to serialize. If this was c#, reflection would make this a trivial task. Given that it's C++, you are almost out of luck.

Comment: Write a preprocessor to add this code to each function. Or look at some of the open-source RTTI libraries (like https://github.com/timkerchmar/tstype). Or document your code (doxygen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
mv::Model::input(const Shape& shape, DType dType, Order order, const string& name)
{
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << "Function [mv::Model::input]- [const Shape&]" << shape.print() << " [DType]" << dType.print()<< " [Order]" << order.print()<< " [const string&]" << name;
    //write to file
    std::ofstream of;
    of.open("file.txt");
    of << ss.rdbuf();
}
```

Add print() member function for each object:

```
    std::string shape::print() const
    { 
       return "round shape";
    }
```